# iOS and Firebase app distribution doesn't want to sign app with development profile and distribute it

Tags: ios, firebase, fastlane, firebase-app-distribution

I have problem with firebase app distribution. 
I am using Xcode 11 and there are new iOS Development certificates, namely Apple Development certificates.

I have added fastlane, added plugin to fastlane for firebase-app-distribution.

But when I am executing my lane to distribute application there is error

```
note: Using new build system
[19:55:21]: ▸ note: Planning build
[19:55:21]: ▸ note: Constructing build description
[19:55:21]: ▸ error: No profile for team 'TEAM_ID' matching 'App Name Development' found: Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching 'TEAM_ID/App Name Development'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the Signing & Capabilities tab of the target editor. (in target 'AppNameDev' from project 'AppName')
```

I have similar configuration and fastlane lane with this plugin for other app but run in Xcode 10, and I think it has old certificates iOS Development not new one Apple Development and it builds and distribute correctly.

I can build this app using Archive, export .ipa and distribute it manually via firebase console and it works.

I have also such error informations

```
 There seems to be a mismatch between your provided `export_method` in gym
[19:55:21]: and the selected provisioning profiles. You passed the following options:
[19:55:21]:   export_method:      
[19:55:21]:   Bundle identifier:  com.company.AppNameDev
[19:55:21]:   Profile name:       App Name Development
[19:55:21]:   Profile type:       development
```

So It just suggest profile name and type and bundle id that I've already correctly types in my Fastfile file in build_ios_app

```
desc "Firebase App Distribution to testers"
  lane :firebase_distribution do 
        build_ios_app(
           workspace: "AppName.xcworkspace", 
                   configuration: "Release", 
           scheme: "AppName Dev",
           silent: true,
           clean: true,
           output_directory: "firebase-builds",
           output_name: "appname.ipa", 
           sdk: "iphoneos13.1",
           export_options: {
                method: "development",
                   provisioningProfiles: { 
                    "com.company.AppNameDev" => "App Name Development"
                   }
            }
        )

        firebase_app_distribution(
                   app: "<id goes here>",
               testers_file: "fastlane/crashlytics_testers.txt",
                   release_notes: "Lots of amazing new features to test out!",
                   firebase_cli_path: "/usr/local/bin/firebase"
                )
    end 
end
```

Comment: Have you checked that the workspace, configuration, and scheme are all correct? It's also possible that your export_options isn't actually doing anything.